FastAPI + Strawberry GraphQL: Issue Setting Cookies in Response (Response object has no attribute
I’m using FastAPI with Strawberry GraphQL and trying to implement a mutation that sets access_token and refresh_token as cookies in the response. However, I’m encountering the following error:
'Response' object has no attribute 'cookies'
from typing import List, Optional, Any
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from redis import Redis
import strawberry
from strawberry.fastapi import BaseContext, GraphQLRouter
from fastapi import Request, Response, Depends
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker, AsyncSession
from src.infrastructure.database.connection import async_session
from src.infrastructure.repositories.user_repository import SQLAlchemyUserRepository
from src.infrastructure.repositories.otp_repository import SQLAlchemyOTPRepository
from src.application.usecases.IEmailUseCase import EmailServiceUseCase
from src.core.config import settings
from src.application.usecases.IUserRegister import UserRegistrationServiceUseCase
from src.infrastructure.config.reddis_config import RedisConfig
from src.__lib.UserRole import UserRole
import logging

# Setting up logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Custom error for registration
class RegistrationError(Exception):
    pass

# Context manager for database session and Redis client
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session

@asynccontextmanager
async def get_redis_client() -> Redis:
    redis_config = RedisConfig()
    redis_client = redis_config.get_client()
    yield redis_client
    redis_client.close()

# Define GraphQL types
@strawberry.type
class RegistrationStatus:
    status: str
    message: str
    email: Optional[str] = None
    created_at: Optional[str] = None
    attempts_remaining: Optional[int] = None
    expires_in: Optional[int] = None

@strawberry.type
class RegistrationResponse:
    message: str
    status: RegistrationStatus

@strawberry.type
class User:
    id: int
    email: str
    is_active: bool
    is_verified: bool
    bio: Optional[str] = None
    profile_image_url: Optional[str] = None
    role: str

@strawberry.type
class VerificationResponse:
    user: User
    access_token: str
    refresh_token: str

@strawberry.input
class UserCreateInput:
    email: str
    password: str
    bio: Optional[str] = None
    profile_image_url: Optional[str] = None

# Custom context with session and Redis client
class CustomContext(BaseContext):
    def __init__(self, request: Request):
        super().__init__()
        self.request: Request = request
        self.session: Optional[AsyncSession] = None
        self.redis_client: Optional[Redis] = None
        self.response: Response = Response()

    async def __aenter__(self):
        async with get_session() as session:
            self.session = session
            async with get_redis_client() as redis_client:
                self.redis_client = redis_client
                return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.session = None
        self.redis_client = None

# GraphQL Query and Mutation definitions
@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    async def users(self, info, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100) -> List[User]:
        async with get_session() as session:
            repository = SQLAlchemyUserRepository(session)
            users = await repository.list_users(skip=skip, limit=limit)
            return [
                User(
                    id=user.id,
                    email=str(user.email),
                    is_active=user.is_active,
                    bio=user.bio,
                    profile_image_url=user.profileImageURL,
                    role=user.role.value,
                )
                for user in users
            ]

@strawberry.type
class Mutation:
    @strawberry.mutation
    async def verify_registration(self, info, email: str, otp: str) -> VerificationResponse:
        context: CustomContext = info.context

        try:
            async with get_redis_client() as redis_client, get_session() as session:
                registration_service = UserRegistrationServiceUseCase(
                    user_repository=SQLAlchemyUserRepository(session),
                    otp_repository=SQLAlchemyOTPRepository(session),
                    email_service=EmailServiceUseCase(),
                    redis_client=redis_client,
                )

                logger.info(f"Verifying OTP for {email}")

                # Verify OTP and retrieve tokens
                user, access_token, refresh_token = await registration_service.verify_otp(email, otp)

                logger.info(f"OTP verified for {email}, issuing access token")

                # Set cookies in the response
                context.response.set_cookie(
                    key="access_token",
                    value=f"Bearer {access_token}",
                    httponly=True,
                    max_age=settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES * 60,  # Convert minutes to seconds
                )
                context.response.set_cookie(
                    key="refresh_token",
                    value=f"Bearer {refresh_token}",
                    httponly=True,
                    max_age=settings.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_DAYS * 24 * 60 * 60,  # Days to seconds
                )

                # Debugging cookie issue
                logger.debug(f"Cookies set in response: {context.response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')}")

                return VerificationResponse(
                    user=User(
                        id=user.id,
                        email=str(user.email),
                        is_active=user.is_active,
                        bio=user.bio,
                        profile_image_url=user.profileImageURL,
                        role=user.role.value,
                        is_verified=user.is_verified,
                    ),
                    access_token=access_token,
                    refresh_token=refresh_token,
                )
        except RegistrationError as e:
            logger.error(f"OTP verification failed for {email}: {str(e)}")
            raise RegistrationError(f"OTP verification failed: {str(e)}")

# Schema and context setup
schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)

async def get_context_with_response(request: Request, response: Response) -> CustomContext:
    context = CustomContext(request)
    context.response = response
    await context.__aenter__()
    return context

graphql_app = GraphQLRouter(schema, context_getter=get_context_with_response)


here in reponse im getting the access_token
{
"data": null,
"errors": [
{
"message": "'Response' object has no attribute 'cookies'",
"locations": [
{
"line": 2,
"column": 3
}
],
"path": [
"verifyRegistration"
]
}
]
}
